# How to create an extra page

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a C# WinForms application. I want to create an extra page (or so called).

For instance: when loading the application you see a screen with a button that says: "Choose character" or "Press start to play" and after that action the real application screen comes up.

Comment: create another form?

Comment: ok so after creating another form. how do I combine the new one with the old one?

Comment: Maybe you want a Splash Screen? You add it to your project by right clicking, you open it first in the program.cs file and from one of its events you open the real main form..

Comment: Side note: please don't put tags in title (like "Windows Forms") and avoid all kind of "new here", "thank you", "did you get me", "urgent" text that is not directly related to your problem. Try to always post code sample you have trouble with.

Comment: I get what you mean. Still too bad that I cannot describe my problem so well. It's just that I want to add an extra "page" to my application like every game has (like settings or dificulty level). Something that does not get you to the mainform every time when you start the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open a second form and then close the first one. In `Program.cs` you will find a code which looks like this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The problem with this code is that your application will terminate as soon as you close `Form1`. Change this code to

```
var frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();
Application.Run();
```

Now the application will not terminate automatically any more. Later, you must terminate the application with `Application.Exit();` (e.g. when the user presses a button). You can also place this code in the `FormClosed` event handler of `Form2` in case the user presses the close-button (X) of the window.

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

You can open a new form like this within `Form1`

```
var frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow following steps if you are building a windows form application:

1. Right click on your project (not on your solution).
2. Click on Add item in the menu that appeared.
3. You should see an option for adding a form. Click on that.
4. Give your form a name.
5. You are done.

I don't see any problem in that

Comment: ye thanks. I added a form. when I start my app I still get form1 instead of combined. Anyway to combine them with the start or am I seeing unclear here? ;p

Comment: Why do you need to combine two forms? You can do things on a single one only..